# PHP Gettext: temporary language switch?

Tags: php, gettext

Is it possible to temporary switch a language with the php gettext module? I would like to change the language since an e-mail should be generated in two language for two different receivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `LC_*` variable(s). Like this:

```
putenv('LC_ALL=de_DE');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');

renderEmail();

putenv('LC_ALL=en_US');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');

renderEmail();
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't new that is was possible to set the LC variable again.